# working with git on not connected computers

Tags: windows, git

I sometimes work in projects where I do development on two computers which are not connected.

A typical example is creating reports in BIDS.
The workflow looks like this:

- I create a project/folder in corporate TFS
- Use git-tfs to create local git repository
- Develop the report and commit to local repository (and some checkins to tfs)
- Clone my repository to the customers computer (using vpn/rdp).
- Do some development on the customers computer and push/pull with my repository.

(Sometimes the work starts in customer end)

My question is now what to do when I don't have a vpn or rdp connection. I have a temporary ftp I can use but sometimes USB-stick is the only way.

I have looked into `format-patch` / `am` but don't understand how I create the initial repository.

Can I just zip the .git folder and unzip in the other end to get started or is there a better way?

`format-patch` seem to create one file per commit. Is there an easy way to merge/unmerge these?
(It is just me working in the project so I don't branch / rebase)

Github might work in some cases but I don't want to open the can of worms with storing customers data in the cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just copy `.git` folders around. Once you have two repositories with a common history, you can use `git-format-patch` and `git-am`.

But probably better suited for your case is the use of [`git-bundle`](http://git-scm.com//docs/git-bundle). It creates binary *bundles* that contain the whole history of a branch from which you can `fetch` and `pull`. The example in the reference page shows nicely how to use it.

Comment: Bundle looks like the exact thing I am looking for. Thanks.